# Add login and password to Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl

First of all I am a one-week self taught when it comes to web service so pardon if this is a duh! question. I was given a sample Web Service and asked to re-create it a new one from scratch. I have been able to understand and apply several of the elements from the original Web Service but I ran into a wall with one. The Web Service has the following element

```
    <s:element name="runQAAS">
        <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element name="login" type="s:string"/>
                <s:element name="password" type="s:string"/>
                <s:element name="createdBy" type="s:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
                <s:element name="createdTo" type="s:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
                <s:element name="modifiedBy" type="s:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
                <s:element name="modifiedTo" type="s:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
```

The user will enter a username and a password given to him/her. The problem is I am not certain how to create a Web Method to ask for the username and password and how to add the entries for username and password to my .asmx file? Also, how can you change the properties of the elements such as `maxOccurs` and `minOccurs`? Just so you know I am using Visual Studio 2010 and programming in C#. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you guys.

Comment: `re-create it a new one from scratch` Microsoft has deprecated asmx. Why not use WebAPI or WCF if you are creating new one from scratch?

Comment: @Win Just because there is a newer technology doesn't mean the old one is deprecated. Though I do agree that using WebAPI is much nicer.

Comment: @DavidG Microsoft recommend not to use ASMX in **new project**. Here are the few reasons that John Saunders wrote - [More Reasons to Not use ASMX Services in New Code](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/)

Comment: @Win Like I said, I agree that new projects should be, for example, WebAPI. I just said that asmx isn't deprecated.

Comment: This might the way we will be moving but right now this is what our vendor is requesting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Criatura, I couldn't add comment so I post a new answer here. I have ever programmed asmx 5 years ago and for security I follow the standard which is WS-Security that is UsernameToken based in that case. MS has WSE 3 that is used to help programming WS-S and maybe other WS-*: http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=14089.
Example of how to use UsernameToken: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19508/WebService-Authentication-with-UsernameToken-in-WS
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @stevenuz, while this is a great tool is does not provide a solution to my problem. The security of username and password is mostly to keep track of who uses the web service. What I need is to create a method that takes the `login`, `password`, and uses the `createdBy` and `createdTo` and the `modifiedBy` and `modifiedTo` to parse the db and produce a result. Thanks for the help and this may be a tolld that I used for future projects.